# Using JUnit to perform an insert

Tags: sql, unit-testing, junit

I need to insert data into a table using JUnit tests.  Is this possible? If so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/).

> DbUnit is a JUnit extension (also usable with Ant) targeted at database-driven projects that, among other things, puts your database into a known state between test runs. This is an excellent way to avoid the myriad of problems that can occur when one test case corrupts the database and causes subsequent tests to fail or exacerbate the damage.
>
> DbUnit has the ability to export and import your database data to and from XML datasets. Since version 2.0, DbUnit can also work with very large datasets when used in streaming mode. DbUnit can also help you to verify that your database data match an expected set of values.

Comment: i have checked it. but could not found any relevant and clear example. i am new to this please give me some complete example

Comment: @Romi, if you didn't understand the [Getting Started](http://www.dbunit.org/howto.html) examples, you won't understand my sample code either. Work your way through the docs and examples, there is no royal road.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JDBC and regular insert statements to do this.

See the Java JDBC tutorial to get started: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/

Comment: i need to use Junit testcases for this. this is the requirement

Comment: You can use regular JDBC calls in a JUnit testcase. A testcase is also "just" a regular Java class

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time to write a sample for you.

You're new to this, so it's likely to be over your head, but I'd recommend that you study some Spring 3 examples even if you don't use Spring.  The ideas will help you to write better tests.

The key is to make your tests transactional: Do your INSERT, check the result, and roll the transaction back when you're done.  It should be as if your test was never there.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html

Comment: Not the best written answer I've seen, but the link is helpful - check the part about test framework and transaction management.

Comment: Certainly better than the comment.  What did this bring to the party?  Nothing that I can see.